# How to update SwiftUI view after @AppStorage in a separate struct gets updated

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a following class:

```
struct PriceFormatter {
    @AppStorage(UserDefaultsKey.savedCurrency)
    var savedCurrency: String?

    let price: Float
    
    init(price: Float) {
        self.price = price
    }
    
    var formatted: String {
        return "\(savedCurrency) \(price)"
    }
}
```

And the following view:

```
struct PriceText: View {
    let price: Float
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(PriceFormatter(price: self.price).formatted)
    }
}
```

I want the view to get rerendered after `savedCurrency` from `UserDefaults` changes.

I made it work easily, when `@AppStorage` was  a part of the view, but I'm not sure what to do in this case. I tried to use `@ObservableObject` with `@Published` or tried to make a Combine `Publisher` and subscribe to it but also had no success.

Comment: `@AppStorage` works *only* in View, by design.

Comment: @Asperi why would they do that?

Comment: @Frankenstein. For the same reason as `@State` do... to give a simplified way dynamically update view when UserDefaults changed... so they are dynamic property wrappers.

Comment: @Asperi interesting, didn't see this mentioned anywhere. thank you!

Comment: What did you do to make this work? this is the exact thing im trying to achieve.

Comment: @andredewaard I did not the nicest thing, but it worked: I just had the `savedCurrency` in every View I needed and then just passed it to the formatter

Comment: Hm I really hoped not to do that haha. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @andredewaard yeah, you’re welcome. Since there’s no such thing for non-Views we have to deal with workarounds. Let me know if you come up with better idea

Comment: @ramzesenok I made a workaround which is easier but maybe more ugly haha. I included AppStorage in all the views I formatted the text in and inside the body function I printed the value to the console and returned the actual view after that. It’s ugly but this way the view knows that value of AppStorage is used inside the view and will update accordingly.

Comment: @andredewaard but why did you need to do this is `View` anyways subscribes to `AppStorage` changes and reloads accordingly? Or you don’t use this value in the `body` directly? Where do you use it then?

Comment: @Asperi iOS 14.5 changed this, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### UPDATE

As pointed by @Klaas starting with iOS 14.5 one can use `@AppStorage` inside the `ObservableObject` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes)

Working solution would now look something like this:

```
class PriceFormatter: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage(UserDefaultsKey.savedCurrency)
    var savedCurrency: String?

    let price: Float
    
    init(price: Float) {
        self.price = price
    }
    
    var formatted: String {
        return "\(savedCurrency) \(price)"
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
struct PriceText: View {
    @StateObject var formatter = PriceFormatter(price: 5)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(formatter.formatted)
    }
}
```

### Old Answer. Valid for iOS < 14.5

As pointed by @Asperi `@AppStorage` should be used only in `View`. Implicitly it is also written here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage

Comment: iOS 14.5 changed this, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes

Comment: @Klaas that’s brilliant, will update the answer once I test it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for posting the iOS 14.5 change, this is great news!

Comment: should be `@StateObject` rather than `@ObservedObject` as you're initializing it within that struct, so that struct will own the object rather than just watching it.

Comment: @godbout you’re right, updated